# Unable to connect to Internet on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I am connected to my university's wifi on my host machine (Windows 7) and I am unable to connect to internet on my guest ubuntu which is running on virtualbox. I do not know what the problem is.  Also, while installing ubuntu when the window pops up that says your installation will run smoothly if you have the following, it doesn't detect my connection to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1). Open the terminal and execute this command.

> ping www.google.com

If it says

> ping: unknown host google.com

you should follow the below mentioned way.

Select the Sharing internet connection (on the hosting OS).

Network Connection Properties -> advanced -> Allow other users to connect...

Comment: Everything is enabled on the host. Also, while looking for solutions, I found out that I don't have vboxuser group on my guest os (Ubuntu)..  I am starting to think that there must have been some problem that occurred while installing ubuntu. I don't know what though. I followed all the instructions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please open the virtual machine and try this, which worked for me.

On the top you find the tool bar for the virtual machine, go there and drop in on

```
    "player">>"Manage">>"Virtual Machine Settings".
```

A new window will be opened.

in the

```
    "Hardware" tab select "Network Adapter".
```

Compare the connection with your windows machine. If it is Bridged or NAT. If you are using a Bridged connection then also check out the configure adapters tab.