# Can't connect to Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 15.10: Intel corporation PRO/wireless 3945ABG adapter

Tags: wireless, 15.10, internet

I can't seem to connect to either the Ethernet or Wi-Fi. I can connect fine from my android phone. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on a Thinkpad T60.

**Edit:**
The ethernet and wireless are separate problems, and the ethernet problem has been solved.

Wifi adapter is **Intel corporation PRO/wireless 3945ABG**.

The results of the wireless info script are too long and stackoverflow won't let me post them, so [here's a link](https://mega.nz/#!71hQwL6L!cxaKSuwzzBEiqxDFrnKOu5NPjaW0E_hx_C1s_ax-FLk).

Comment: If you have dual boot, can you try connecting from Windows?What is your wifi adaptor?

Comment: I don't have dual boot -- my hard drive is only 60gb. my WiFi adaptor is Intel corporation PRO/wireless 3945ABG [Golan], but Ethernet doesn't work eithrr

Comment: Would be nice if you could explain what you meant by other devices? Also, your interface files doesn't have any NIC informations. However, I cannot seem to edit your post with the image, so can you re-upload it an image host like [**imgur**](http://imgur.com)

Comment: By other devices, I mean Android and a few gaming consoles. What is NIC information? I'll upload to imgur now.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. Also, please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Comment: Normally I would do all of what you sy, but the only device I currently have that can access the internet is my phone. I'll try to update if I get access to another computer.

Comment: Please use [Ubuntu pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) for posting logs. Please move your log to ubuntu pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

if your host is a Windows then using a Virtual Machine try the below link

[Explained about VM Ware Internet Settings when using Bridged or NAT connections](https://askubuntu.com/a/774092/455904)